# How many epochs to run during hyperparameter search?

Tags: training, hyperparameter, hyperparameter-tuning

If I'm doing a hyperparameter search and comparing two different hyperparameters (but not number of epochs), is there some established rule of thumb for how many epochs to run?  If I just compare after a few epochs, will that give me a good idea about how it will perform fully converged (say for example after 1000 epochs).  Is there any research papers where people have studied this question?

Answer (score 1):

The general rule of thumb is to run the number of epochs until validation error starts to increase.

Sometimes fast initial learning will not lead to the best performance later.